# How to exit silently in OCaml, without exceptions

Tags: ocaml

Suppose i'am deep in the stack and something happens and now i just want to exit. 
`failwith` won't do for me because it's not silent at all.
I tried `failwith ""` and i got `Fatal error: exception Failure("")`
I need something similar to `exit 0` in C.

Comment: My question is, why do you want to exit without any output?  How are you going to know you have an issue or unexpected situation?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
exit 0
```

It works exactly like exit(0); in C.

The most basic operations like this are in the [Pervasives](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html) module. Every time I read through the Pervasive docs I notice something I forgot since the previous time.

Comment: In a if condition if something turns out to be true i need to print a message and then exit. Problem is that it won't let me use exit 0. I tried `if cond then print_string "Sucess\n"; exit 0` Must be problem with types, i have else condition too. How to handle this?

Comment: This is a separate question, with little to no information on the error you're seeing. When I try this code it "lets" me, it just exits unconditionally. My best guess: use parentheses: `if cond then (print_string "X"; exit 0)`.

Comment: I have no idea, you gave zero information :-) It doesn't help to hear that it doesn't "let" you do something. You have to show your actual code, transcribe the specific error message you saw, describe what happened that you weren't expecting, etc.

Comment: @power_output the problem is that `if e1 then instr1; instr2` is interpreted (and compiled) as `(if e1 then instr1); instr2` so `instr2` is not in the then branch ;-)